# Hibernate mapping for parameterized classes

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, mapping

I've been wondering for some time if it was possible to use Hibernate with parameterized classes.

Can it handle something like this? Is there some other way to do it?

```
class Auto<Autotyp extends Fahrzeugtyp>{
   Autotyp type;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please post in English on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate deals with parameerized Collection types all the time. Mappings are all processed at runtime anyway, when most type information has been removed.

Comment: In this case we know the Typeparamter. (set<String>)
Mapping looks like:
    <set name="annotations">
      <key column="ID" />
      <element column="annotation" type="string"/>
    </set>

But how does it work in my case?

Comment: @Heman: A Set<String> is mapped that way because it's a collection mapping, and hibernate has to be told the type of objects that are in the collection. Your class would be just another entity class. An association to it would be mapped something like: `<many-to-one name="property name"/>`. That's it